# How to create a tool that builds signed apk in Android?

Tags: android, makefile, apk

How to make a tool for Android that builds a signed apk as game maker tools.

I searched everywhere  but couldn't find tutorial website for this topic.. .

Anyone please guide me.. ..
Thank you alot.. ...

Comment: i think they provide built in facility still you can tell game maker tool name

Comment: I want to develop a tool like game maker for Android which takes some variables and creates a new custom apk ... How can I do that?